# MotionLayout - Animate without event

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

In my scene that I want to animate I have some animation that is triggered by an on click event. 
But I also have some bits that I want to animate in the background and on repeat that are not triggered by anything. Can I use motionlayout to create animation that just loops and needs no trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can't. MotionLayout is designed to create an easier way to animate transitions between two scenes, and not to be used as an animator for views.

But you can always use a work around (which is not "pretty", yeah I know):

```
class AnimationTask(val motionLayout: MotionLayout, val handler: Handler) : Runnable {

    override fun run() {
        if (fragmentOrActivityIsDestroyed) {
            return
        }

        when (motionLayout.currentState) {
            R.id.sceneEnd -> motionLayout.transitionToStart()
            R.id.sceneStart -> motionLayout.transitionToEnd()
        }

        handler.postDelayed(this, yourDelay)
    }
}

Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).apply {
   postDelayed(AnimationTask(motionLayout, this), yourDelay)
}
```

**Edit**

As stated [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/motion/MotionLayout):

> This Layout supports transitions between constraint sets defined in MotionScenes
>
> A MotionLayout is a ConstraintLayout which allows you to animate layouts between various states.

Comment: Ahh thank-you. After posting this I did find something like the above. It does work... and like you say, not pretty.

Comment: Could you provide source where it elaborates about Motionlayout being made for transitioning between two scenes instead of an animator for views?

Comment: @GV_FiQst can you elaborate on your answer? What is `fragmentOrActivityIsDestroyed`? I'm also looking to do "Animate in the background and on repeat that are not triggered by anything. Can I use motionlayout to create animation that just loops and needs no trigger?"

I have a square that I need to alpha to a sin wave, and I also need to move the square from the left of the screen to the right. Should I have two different motion layouts?

Comment: @coltonidle Addressing your question: `fragmentOrActivityIsDestroyed` is just pseudocode (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode), showing that if your hosting activity or fragment destroyed you should do animation to avoid exceptions

Comment: @coltonidle I don't know what exactly you are trying to achieve but as I see it you don't need MotionLayout at all. All you need is `android.view.animation.Animation` (which can be loaded from xml btw, with `AnimationUtils.loadAnimation()`), it can animate your views alpha and position and also it can do loops. Just call `yourView.startAnimation(myAnimation)`

Comment: I'm trying to use this animation at the same time of another MotionLayout animation and trying to implement with an object animator completely bricks MotionLayout.

I was able to get an answer for Nicolas Roard. Apparently just having an animation blink can be completed through a KeyTimeCycle instead of a KeyCycle